# 'struct queue' has no member named 'next'.

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I have tried to implement Queue using linked list using the following structures. But in enqueue function, just below the comment i am getting the above mentioned error.This error had occured while the same is used in the code given at this link http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-set-2-linked-list-implementation/. There is a comment which I used to run the code. But i dont understand why i am getting this error. Please help !

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    };

    struct queue
    {
        struct queue *front;
        struct queue *rear;
    };

    struct queue* createQueue();
    void enqueue(struct queue *q,int info);
    int dequeue(struct queue *q);
    void display(struct queue *q);
    int isEmpty(struct queue *q);
    void menu();

    struct queue* createQueue()
    {
        struct queue *new_queue; 
        new_queue = (struct queue*) malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
        if(new_queue != NULL)
        {
            return ;
        } 
        new_queue->front = new_queue->rear = NULL;
        return new_queue;
    }
    int isEmpty(struct queue *q)
    {
        if(q->front == NULL)
            return 1;
    }

    void enqueue(struct queue *q,int info)
    {
        struct node *temp,*temp1;
        temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if(temp == NULL)
            return ;
        temp->data = info;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(q->front == NULL && q->rear == NULL)
        {
            q->front = temp;
            q->rear = temp;
        }
        if(q->rear != NULL)
        {
            //temp1 = q->rear;
            q->rear->next = temp;
            q->rear = temp;
        }
    }

    int dequeue(struct queue *q)
    {
        if(isEmpty(q) == 1)
        {
            printf("Empty list!");
        }
        struct node *temp = q->front;
        q->front = temp->next;
        int data = temp->data;
        free(temp);
        return (data);
    }

    void display(struct queue *q)
    {
        struct node *start,*end = NULL;
        start = q->front;
        end = q->rear;
        if(isEmpty(q) == 1)
        {
            printf("Empty List!");
        }
        while(start != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d",start->data);
            start = start->next;
        }
    }

    void menu()
    {
        int choice = 0;
        int input = 0;
        struct queue *q;
        while(1)
        {
            printf("\t\tMain Menu\n");
            printf("\t0.Create Queue\n");
            printf("\t1.Enqueue\n");
            printf("\t2.Dequeue\n");
            printf("\t3.Display\n");
            printf("\t4.Exit\n");
            printf("\tEnter the desired choice:");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 0:
                    q = createQueue();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("\tEnter the data:");
                    scanf("%d",&input);
                    enqueue(q,input);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("%d",dequeue(q));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    display(q);
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    exit(0);
                default:
                    printf("\tThe value is invalid!");
            }
        }

    }

    int main()
    {
        menu();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you are writing

```
q->rear->next = temp;
```

`rear` is a `queue` struct, not a `node` struct.

You wrote this:

```
struct queue
{
    struct queue *front;
    struct queue *rear;
};
```

but from the terms you used I think that it should be this:

```
struct queue
{
    struct node *front;
    struct node *rear;
};
```

(of course the error line will become OK but you may have other problems all around :))

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Though it was a silly mistake and quite embarrassing! But can you tell me the other mistakes that you just referred to !

Answer (score 2):

The answer is infront of you.

You are defining the queue struct with front and rear and there is no member named `next` in it.

You probably have used the pointer of queue type with the member `next` which is the member of `struct node` and not `struct queue`

Here's the mistake

```
q->rear->next = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would re-write your code (see notes bellow)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define EMPTY 1
// No need for struct node at all!
struct queue
{
    int data;
    struct queue *front;
    struct queue *rear;
};

struct queue* createQueue();
void enqueue(struct queue *q,int info);
int dequeue(struct queue *q);
void display(struct queue *q);
int isEmpty(struct queue *q);
void menu();

struct queue* createQueue()
{
    struct queue *new_queue; 
    new_queue = (struct queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct queue)); 
    if(new_queue != NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    } 
    new_queue->front = new_queue->rear = NULL;
    return new_queue;
}
int isEmpty(struct queue *q)
{
    if(q == NULL|| q->front == NULL) //`q` might be NULL also, so that q->front won't cause segmentation fault.
        return EMPTY; //check the #define above.
}

void enqueue(struct queue *q,int info)
{
    if (q == NULL) return; /*ALWAYS check for null pointer before dereference*/
    struct queue *temp,*temp1; // changed node to queue
    temp = (struct queue*) malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if(temp == NULL) return ;
    temp->data = info;
    temp->front = NULL; //changed `next' to `front', check if this is OK.
    if(q->front == NULL && q->rear == NULL)
    {
        q->front = temp;
        q->rear = temp;
    }
    if(q->rear != NULL)
    {            
        q->rear->front = temp; //changed `next' to `front', check if this is OK.
        q->rear = temp;
    }
}

int dequeue(struct queue *q)
{
    if(isEmpty(q) == EMPTY)
    {
        printf("Empty list!");
    }
    struct queue *temp = q->front; //changed node to queue
    q->front = temp->front;//changed `next' to `front', check if this is OK.
    int data = temp->data;
    free(temp);
    return (data);
}

void display(struct queue *q)
{
    if (!q) return;
    struct queue *start,*end = NULL; //changed node to queue
    start = q->front;
    end = q->rear;
    if(isEmpty(q) == 1)
    {
        printf("Empty List!");
    }
    while(start != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",start->data);
        start = start->front;//changed `next' to `front', check if this is OK.
    }
}

void menu()
{
    int choice = 0;
    int input = 0;
    struct queue *q;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\t\tMain Menu\n");
        printf("\t0.Create Queue\n");
        printf("\t1.Enqueue\n");
        printf("\t2.Dequeue\n");
        printf("\t3.Display\n");
        printf("\t4.Exit\n");
        printf("\tEnter the desired choice:");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0:
                q = createQueue();
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("\tEnter the data:");
                scanf("%d",&input);
                enqueue(q,input);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("%d",dequeue(q));
                break;
            case 3:
                display(q);
                break;
            case 4: 
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("\tThe value is invalid!");
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTES**

- added the field `data` in the struct `queue`
- You were dereferencing `q` without checking if it's `NULL` or not! this may cause you `segmentation fault`.
- There is no need for struct `node` in the code at all! think about it

Comment: nice proposal. I would have added some `const queue *` for consultation methods (check empty, display) to tell the users that the object is not modified by call.